# Displaying a Drop-Down List While Editing in the GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a datagrid which shows the search reasult(time entered by the user preveiously)on a button click event depending uppon the input name or date enter by the user,i want to show a drop down list for a field selection like depertment whenever user want to edit the data in datagridiew,i am using access database & asp3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Template Columns to specify a dropdown list for when you edit a datagrid.  You can also do a bit more on the code side if you want to do things dynamically, but the Template Columns will allow you to override the standard textbox that shows when you edit.